# Docker : how to create and use configmap in docker

Tags: docker

I need to implement the following things in dockerfile
We have a sqlhost value defined in a file for database connection which later feeds to dockerfile using ADD
Now we are going to pass sql host value dynamically to dockerfile using configmaps

reading those config maps as environmental variables in sqlhost file

I have a requirement like whenever i feed values to dockerfile the sqlhost takes the value dynamically
Please suggest me how i can achieve this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What did you try to solve this issue 
and what problem did you encounter?

Comment: Please tell if there s any other options?

Comment: We are manually feeding the sqlhost value to dockerfile at build time,now we are planning to give sqlhost value dynamically to dockerfile,so is there a way to feed to dockerfile ? Or is it possible to do with configmap?

Comment: Environment variables are the usual mechanism.  Plain Docker doesn't have an equivalent of Kubernetes ConfigMaps.  For small applications Docker Compose can be a straightforward way to provide these settings.

Comment: David Maze if you could help me with other option it would be helpful? or someone can help me with other option if available Thanks in advance